# while Loop issue with java

Tags: java

I have two loops that I cant seem to work properly. Basically, if I write something incorrectly, it sends me to a point where I have to write it correctly. When I got to that point, regardless of what I type, I cannot leave the input. Any line that says "Invalid" is not giving me the results i need. Please help me out! Here is the code.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class EZRealEstateSimulator {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    /* Declarations */
        String buy = "Buy";
        String rent = "Rent";
        String sell = "Sell";
        String quit = "Quit";       
    String [] availableHomes;
        availableHomes = new String [6];
        availableHomes [0] = "516 Dunkin St, Ontario, CA";
        availableHomes [1] = "224 Mooclid Ave, Ontario, CA";
        availableHomes [2] = "342 Pine Ave, Chino Hills, CA";
        availableHomes [3] = "1488 Overprice Ave, Chino Hills, CA";
        availableHomes [4] = "632 Clayton Drive, Chino Hills, CA";
        availableHomes [5] = "778 Lakeside Ct, Rancho Cucamonga, CA";
    String [] availableApartments;
        availableApartments = new String [6];
        availableApartments [0] = "1248 Helm St, APT: 678, Rancho Cucamonga,CA";
        availableApartments [1] = "892 Low Park Ave, APT:32, Rancho Cucamonga,CA";
        availableApartments [2] = "120 Maven Ct, APT: 55, Ontario,CA";
        availableApartments [3] = "423 Scimitar St, APT: 12, Ontario,CA";
        availableApartments [4] = "918 Mystic Parkway, APT:3, Rancho Cucamonga,CA";
        availableApartments [5] = "1316 Cobalt Ct, APT: 27, Chino Hills,CA";
        String [] activeCities;
        activeCities = new String [3];
        activeCities [0] = "Ontario";
        activeCities [1] = "Rancho Cucamonga";
        activeCities [2] = "Chino Hills";
    String house = "House";
    String apartment = "Apartment";
    int [] paymentPlan;
        paymentPlan = new int [4];
        paymentPlan [0] = 250;
        paymentPlan [1] = 500;
        paymentPlan [2] = 750;
        paymentPlan [3] = 1000;
        int downPayment = 200;
    String completeReport;
    int changeLoop;
        int changeAltLoop;
    String customerAddress = " ";
    String customerCellNumber = " ";
    String customerHomeNumber = " ";
        String customerName = " ";
        String housingTenure;
        String livingArea;
        String cities;
        String purchasedHome = " ";
        String purchasedApartment = " ";
        int errorLoop;
        int gameLoop;


        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

    /* Personal Info Prompts */


        System.out.println("Would you like to buy, or quit program? Type Buy or Quit "); 
        housingTenure = input.nextLine ();

        System.out.println("Would this be for an apartment or home? Type House or Apartment");
        livingArea = input.nextLine ();

        System.out.println("Please enter your full name: ");
        String name = input.nextLine ();
        customerName = name;

        System.out.println("Please enter your full address: ");
        String address = input.nextLine ();
        customerAddress = address;

        System.out.println("Please enter your home number: ");
        String hNumber = input.nextLine ();
        customerHomeNumber = hNumber;

        System.out.println("Please enter your cell number: ");
        String cNumber = input.nextLine ();
        customerCellNumber = cNumber;

gameLoop = 0;
while (gameLoop == 0) {

                /* Buy */

                changeLoop = 0;
                while (changeLoop == 0 && livingArea.equals(house)) {                
                    System.out.println("Which city would you like to buy property in? Type Ontario, Chino Hills, or Rancho Cucamonga ");
                    cities = input.nextLine ();
                if (!cities.equals(activeCities [0]) || !cities.equals(activeCities [1]) || !cities.equals(activeCities [2])) {
                    System.out.println("Invalid. Please enter either Ontario, Chino Hills, or Rancho Cucamonga");
                    cities = input.nextLine ();
                } else {
                        continue;
                    }

                    if (cities.equals(activeCities [0])) {
                        System.out.println("The available homes are: " + availableHomes [0] +  " and "   + availableHomes [1] + " .Please select one by typing availableHomes [#] ");
                        purchasedHome = input.nextLine ();
                        if (!purchasedHome.equals(availableHomes[0]) || !purchasedHome.equals(availableHomes [1])) {
                            System.out.println("Invalid");
                            purchasedHome = input.nextLine ();
                        } else { 
                            changeLoop += 1;
                        }                       
                    } else if (cities.equals(activeCities [1])) {
                        System.out.println("The available homes are: " + availableHomes [5] +  " .Please select one by typing availableHomes [#] ");
                        purchasedHome = input.nextLine ();
                        if (!purchasedHome.equals(availableHomes[5])) {
                            System.out.println("Invalid");
                            purchasedHome = input.nextLine ();
                        } else { 
                            changeLoop += 1;
                        }   

                    } else {
                        System.out.println("The available homes are: " + availableHomes [2] +  " , "  + availableHomes [3] +  " and "  + availableHomes [4] +  " .Please select one by typing availableHomes [#] ");
                        purchasedHome = input.nextLine ();
                        if (!purchasedHome.equals(availableHomes[2]) || !purchasedHome.equals(availableHomes [3]) || !purchasedHome.equals(availableHomes [4])) {
                            System.out.println("Invalid");
                            purchasedHome = input.nextLine ();
                        } else { 
                            changeLoop += 1;
                        }   
                    }
                }

                changeAltLoop = 0;
                while (changeAltLoop == 0 && livingArea.equals(apartment)) {   
                    System.out.println("Which city would you like to buy property in? Type Ontario, Chino Hills, or Rancho Cucamonga ");
                    cities = input.nextLine ();
                    if (!cities.equals(activeCities [0]) || !cities.equals(activeCities [1]) || !cities.equals(activeCities [2])) {
                    System.out.println("Invalid. Please enter either Ontario, Chino Hills, or Rancho Cucamonga");
                    cities = input.nextLine ();
                    }
                    if (cities.equals(activeCities [0])) {                  
                    System.out.println("The available apartments are: " + availableApartments [2] + " and " + availableApartments [3]);
                    purchasedApartment = input.nextLine ();
                        if (!purchasedApartment.equals(availableApartments[2]) || !purchasedApartment.equals(availableApartments [3])) {
                            System.out.println("Invalid");
                            purchasedApartment = input.nextLine ();                  
                    } else if (cities.equals(activeCities [1])) {
                    System.out.println("The available apartments are: " + availableApartments [0] + " , " + availableApartments [1] + " and " + availableApartments [4]);
                    purchasedApartment = input.nextLine ();
                       if (!purchasedApartment.equals(availableApartments [0]) || !purchasedApartment.equals(availableApartments [1])) {
                            System.out.println("Invalid");
                            purchasedApartment = input.nextLine ();
                       }
                       } else {
                    System.out.println("The available apartments are: " + availableApartments [5]);
                    purchasedApartment = input.nextLine ();
                        if (!purchasedApartment.equals(availableApartments [5])) { 
                            System.out.println("Invalid");
                            purchasedApartment = input.nextLine ();
                        } else { 
                            changeAltLoop += 1;
                        }
                    }
                }
                }


                    /* eof */

                    System.out.println("Please select a monthly payment plan price: " + paymentPlan [0] + " , " + paymentPlan [1] + " , " + paymentPlan [2] + " and " + paymentPlan [3]);
                    System.out.println("REMAINDER! Each payment is due on the 5th of each month and a $200 down payment is required.");
                    int payment = input.nextInt ();

                    System.out.println("Processing data into detailed report...");
                    System.out.println("                                       ");
                    System.out.println("                                       ");
                    System.out.println("                                       ");

                    System.out.println("---Complete Report---");
                    System.out.println("Customer Name: " + name);
                    System.out.println("Customer Address: " + address);
                    System.out.println("Customer Home Number: " + hNumber);
                    System.out.println("Customer Cell Number: " + cNumber);
                    System.out.println("Customer Payment Plan: " + payment);
                    System.out.println("Customer Purchased House: " + purchasedHome);
                    System.out.println("Customer Purchased Apartment: " + purchasedApartment);



                }   

                }       
                }
```

Comment: You're asking people to trawl through 192 lines of code, looking for some loops somewhere that are misbehaving in some vague way. Could you try to [reduce your code to something simpler](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and describe your problem a little better?

Comment: what are the chances that you copies this from some web site and it did not run?

Answer (score 1):

That is a lot of code :)
Anway the issue you stated is due to your if condition

```
if (!cities.equals(activeCities[0]) || !cities.equals(activeCities[1]) || !cities.equals(activeCities[2])) {
    System.out.println("Invalid. Please enter either Ontario, Chino Hills, or Rancho Cucamonga");
    cities = input.nextLine();
} else {
    continue;
}
```

Since you are using an OR (||) operation it goes through all condition until it finds a true. So in order skip this loop all expressions should return false that means the entered city should be equal to all activeCities which is not possible. So it'll show invalid all the time. So first change the logic to

```
if (!cities.equals(activeCities[0]) && !cities.equals(activeCities[1]) && !cities.equals(activeCities[2])) {
    System.out.println("Invalid. Please enter either Ontario, Chino Hills, or Rancho Cucamonga");
    cities = input.nextLine();
}
```

Also note the else condition. You should remove the entire else because a continue statement from here result in re iterting the while loop and it keeps on askin the same question over and over again as long as you enter valid city.

**Quick tips**

- Using `equalsIgnoreCase` comparison would be better as the user may
  type "house" instead of "House"
- Use Collections API like List, Map etc instead of array. This would
  make comparisons like above ifs to
  `if(!activeCities.contains(cities))`. Code will be concise and
  cleaner.

**A complete example**

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeMap;
import java.util.TreeSet;

public class EZRealEstateSimulator {

    private static final Set<String> activeCities, propertyOptions, commands;
    private static final Map<String, Set<String>> availableHomes, availableApartments;
    private static final String[] prompts = new String[9];
    private static final int[] paymentPlan = { 250, 500, 750, 1000 };
    private static final int downPayment = 200;

    private static String userOption, customerAddress, customerCellNumber, customerHomeNumber, customerName, propertyType, city, purchasedHome, purchasedApartment, customerPaymentPlan;
    private static int i = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        do {
            System.out.println(getPrompt(i));
            String value = input.nextLine();
            if(!isValidOption(value, i)){
                System.out.println("Invalid Option!!");
                continue;
            }
            i++;
        } while(i < 9);
        input.close();

        System.out.println("Processing data into detailed report...");
        System.out.println("                                       ");
        System.out.println("                                       ");
        System.out.println("                                       ");
        System.out.println("---Complete Report---");
        System.out.println("Customer Name: " + customerName);
        System.out.println("Customer Address: " + customerAddress);
        System.out.println("Customer Home Number: " + customerHomeNumber);
        System.out.println("Customer Cell Number: " + customerCellNumber);
        System.out.println("Customer Payment Plan: " + customerPaymentPlan);
        System.out.println("Customer Purchased House: " + purchasedHome);
        System.out.println("Customer Purchased Apartment: " + purchasedApartment);
    }

    private static String getPrompt(int index) {
        String message = prompts[index];

        switch (index) {
            case 6: //City Question
                message = String.format(message, activeCities.toString());
                break;

            case 7: //Available house/apartment question
                String opts = ("House".equalsIgnoreCase(propertyType) ? join(availableHomes.get(city)) : join(availableApartments.get(city)));
                message = String.format(message, propertyType, opts);
                break;

            case 8: //Payment Question
                message = String.format(message, Arrays.toString(paymentPlan), downPayment);
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }

        return message;
    }

    private static boolean isValidOption(String value, int index) {
        boolean isValid = true;

        switch (index) {
            case 0:
                userOption = value;
                isValid = commands.contains(value.toUpperCase());
                if(isValid && "Quit".equalsIgnoreCase(userOption)){
                    i = 10; // Breaks out of main while loop.
                }
                break;
            case 1:
                propertyType = value;
                isValid = propertyOptions.contains(value.toUpperCase());
                break;
            case 2:
                customerName = value;
                break;
            case 3:
                customerAddress = value;
                break;
            case 4:
                customerHomeNumber = value;
                break;
            case 5:
                customerCellNumber = value;
                break;
            case 6:
                city = value;
                isValid = activeCities.contains(value);
                break;
            case 7:
                if ("House".equalsIgnoreCase(propertyType)) {
                    purchasedHome = value;
                    isValid = availableHomes.get(city).contains(value);
                } else {
                    purchasedApartment = value;
                    isValid = availableApartments.get(city).contains(value);
                }
                break;
            case 8:
                customerPaymentPlan = value;
                try {
                    if (Arrays.binarySearch(paymentPlan, Integer.parseInt(value)) == -1) {
                        isValid = false;
                    }
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    isValid = false;
                }
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }

        return isValid;
    }

    public static String join(Set<String> array) {
    final int noOfItems = array.size();
    final StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder(noOfItems * 16);
    int idx = 0;
    for (String value : array) {
        if (idx > 0) {
        buf.append("\n");
        }
        idx++;
        buf.append(idx + ". " + value);
    }
    return buf.toString();
    }

    // Initialize constants
    static {
        availableHomes = new TreeMap<String, Set<String>>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
        availableHomes.put("Ontario", new TreeSet<String>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER) {{ add("516 Dunkin St, Ontario, CA"); add("224 Mooclid Ave, Ontario, CA"); }});
        availableHomes.put("Chino Hills", new TreeSet<String>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER) {{ add("342 Pine Ave, Chino Hills, CA"); add("1488 Overprice Ave, Chino Hills, CA"); add("632 Clayton Drive, Chino Hills, CA"); }});
        availableHomes.put("Rancho Cucamonga", new TreeSet<String>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER) {{ add("778 Lakeside Ct, Rancho Cucamonga, CA"); }});

        availableApartments = new TreeMap<String, Set<String>>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
        availableApartments.put("Rancho Cucamonga", new TreeSet<String>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER) {{ add("1248 Helm St, APT: 678, Rancho Cucamonga,CA"); add("892 Low Park Ave, APT:32, Rancho Cucamonga,CA"); add("918 Mystic Parkway, APT:3, Rancho Cucamonga,CA"); }});
        availableApartments.put("Ontario", new TreeSet<String>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER) {{ add("120 Maven Ct, APT: 55, Ontario,CA"); add("423 Scimitar St, APT: 12, Ontario,CA"); }});
        availableApartments.put("Chino Hills", new TreeSet<String>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER) {{ add("1316 Cobalt Ct, APT: 27, Chino Hills,CA"); }});

        activeCities = new TreeSet<String>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
        activeCities.addAll(Arrays.asList(new String[] {"Ontario", "Rancho Cucamonga", "Chino Hills"}));

        propertyOptions = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(new String[] { "HOUSE", "APARTMENT" }));
        commands = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(new String[] { "BUY", "QUIT" }));

        prompts[0] = "Would you like to buy, or quit program? Type Buy or Quit";
        prompts[1] = "Would this be for an apartment or home? Type House or Apartment";
        prompts[2] = "Please enter your full name: ";
        prompts[3] = "Please enter your full address: ";
        prompts[4] = "Please enter your home number: ";
        prompts[5] = "Please enter your cell number: ";
        prompts[6] = "Which city would you like to buy property in? Options %s :";
        prompts[7] = "The available %s are:\n%s\nPlease select one by typing availableHomes [#] ";
        prompts[8] = "Please select a monthly payment plan price: %s \n REMAINDER! Each payment is due on the 5th of each month and a $%s down payment is required.";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Sorry if it was a bit much. Thought someone would have wanted to see everything. btw, cut me some slack. Still getting use to coding... anyways, i am having issues with the changeLoop and changeAltLoop. When I access the changeLoop, it prompts me to select the city as it should but when I type either the correct or incorrect value, I will get an "invalid" message. If i type the same incorrect or correct value, it will bypass the prompt and go to the next one. When I access the changeAltLoop, no prompts appear after "Please enter your cell number: ."

Comment: Can you brief the requirement. I assume you need to enter House or Apartment and get Details of it and show as report? And it'll always be one house or apartment. Is that it?

Comment: Exactly what you said in a nut shell. I can shorten. What would you suggest I scrap from it.

Comment: Hey, your improved code fixed everything. Thanks for the help!

Comment: There are many powerful features in collections api that comes out of the box. You could rely on that. I've updated my answer with a program that uses some of it. You can use that for a kick-start. Anyway the program is complete. ;)